# Maximum session duration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-signalr

Using SignalR Core, I want clients to re-authenticate every 4 hours. How would I abort connections on the server-side that are still open after 4 hours?

What I've tried:

```cs
// Inside my Hub
public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
    Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(4)).ContinueWith(_ => Context.Abort());
}
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work because the Context is disposed once the connection is established.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this something you would delegate to an authentication provider? Or do you have your own identity management system?

Try to access a straightforward (fast - health-check - heartbeat, whatever you want to name it) resource. If authentication has expired you'll get an error (most likely something like 440, 401 or even 403) and then the client side will know about the need for (re-)authentication - you will have to hook it into there though.

Then again, the async nature of SignalR might struggle with this; or there is an out-of-the-box pattern/solution - so maybe that is your question?

Comment: My problem with SignalR is that authentication middleware runs before establishing a connection. A WebSockets connection can outlive the lifetime of the authentication cookie/token. I'm looking for a way to forcefully close connections so that the client has to re-authenticate.